# Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.4.0

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

A have no idea how to fix it. Here's my code:

**build.gradle(:app)**

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }

dependencies {
    constraints {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
    }
```

**android root build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 31
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2')
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

React-native cli
Gradle version = 6.9-rc-1
Android Gradle Plugin version = 4.2.2

So the thing is that the debug build variant is actually working. As soon as i switching to release build variant - it's not building.

I've tried almost every solution on a stackoverflow. I've cleaned project, deleted cache folder manually, changing versions about 30 times and still nothing. Can someone explain what the hell is wrong with this code?
Thank you!